# How can I edit/Update the launch screen text in react-native app(Xcode)

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I need to update my app name in launch/splash screen.

How can I update my launch screens name?

Can any one give the steps how to update the launch screen text?

Answer (score 1):

I have Changed the LaunchScreen.xib in Xcode

```
 <string key="text">Renamed </string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should :

1) Change class in index.js file from App.js to whichever class you want

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import routes from './src/Routes';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => routes);
```

2) Create Route file

```
import React from 'react'
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Splash from './Splash'
import Calc from './Calc'

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
        {
            Splash: Splash,
            Calc: Calc,
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: 'Splash',
        },
    ),
)

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <AppContainer />;
    }
}
```

3) Create desired splash screen

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    Image,
    View
} from 'react-native';
import Style from './Style'

class Splash extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Calc')
        }, 1500)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={Style.splashContainer}>
                <Image
                    source={{ uri: 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ios7-inspired-mac-icon-set/1024/Calculator_5122x.png' }}
                    style={Style.splashImage}
                />
                <Text style={Style.splashText}>Calculator</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default Splash
```

In this last file you can design your splash screen however you want

That's how you can create custom launcher screen and splash screen in react native

Thank you